# Does this sound like HDD PCB fail?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

The hard disk in my laptop has completely died, bios doesn't even recognise that a HD is connected, and power on quickly halts with `No bootable device -- Please restart system`.

The laptop was zipping many files when it died, so had spent 20+min at 100% CPU and high HDD load.

I've opened it up and checked for loose connections and there are no visible scortch marks or damage.

The HDD sounds like it spins up normally when it first gets power, for about 4 seconds, then silence.  No clicking or abnormal noise.

I am considering trying a replacement PCB to get the data off it, or alternatively buy a adapter to mount it in a desktop and test it, but would like to know what the odds are that either of those would work.

Does it sounds like motherboard, PCB or something else?

Comment: It could be anything to be honestly bit the drive does indeed sound like its dead

Comment: What do you mean when you say PCB?  Are you saying the SATA controller on your motherboard, the hard drive controller on the drive, or something else?  In any case, there are way too many possibilities . . . if it were me, first thing I would try is putting the HDD in another laptop or an external bay . . .

Comment: It may well be the controller (PCB) that has died, but it isn't as simple as getting another one, as there is drive specific firmware in the PCB.  You'd need an exact replacement, ideally from the same manufacturing batch as the one you have, and even then it is hit and miss.

Comment: @Paul thanks, that's the sort of "odds" info I need.  The unbacked-up data on there isn't super important, so I won't spend a lot on it, but if $40 on a replacement controller PCB sounded like it would have a good shot at fixing it, then that would have been a convenience worth having.

Answer (score 2):

3 decades of dealing with disks & data says: Odds are extremely good that if you don't have the NSA's budget, you are going to kiss whatever data was on there goodbye. For free you can try the old freezer trick (put either the whole laptop or just the hard drive in a sealed plastic bag in the freezer for a good long time [overnight, or at least 4 hours], then power it up and pray) and the minor fiddles like setting the computer so the hard drive is on edge when you fire it up. Those things occasionally work - but not with any sort of guarantee that they **will** work on any particular failed disk when you happen to need them to. Just often enough to give them a whirl. If they do work, grab data as fast as you can, most important first, since they don't generally work for long.

Chalk it up to experience and learn from it that your data is only as good as your latest backup (and if you don't know that your latest backup is good, that may not be very good...)

You can, of course, start throwing money at disk recovery services, but you may not get satisfaction from doing so (you will definitely end up poorer, though.)

Comment: The freezer trick works for me about half the time, provided the computer owner doesn't keep trying & trying to make the disk work beforehand.

Comment: What is the logic behind the freezer trick?

Comment: Purely engineering practice - that it sometimes works. I've never seen a reason/theory offered that appeared to be any more than someone guessing. Here's a thread with a few more good and bad experiences with it. http://superuser.com/questions/1078/harddrive-in-the-freezer-ever-work-for-you

Comment: Based on the comments on that questions, it sounds like the idea is to temporarily free up the bearings.  Since this spins up for 4 seconds then stops, I suspect it won't help here.  Costs nothing to try though.

Comment: Logic behind the freezer trick is that thermal expansion (or in this case contraction) will free things up - whether it be the head, bearings, what not, the logic is that something will get moved closer to the original position (assumption being that a drive that's seen use has experienced lots of thermal expansion, some of which may have been inelastic).

Comment: Yes, a few commentators there claim that freeing up the bearings "is the only thing it does." I see nothing to convince **me** that they are particularly authoritative, and I've seen it "work" on drives that spun up just fine but didn't "work," so my experience says they don't *know* what they are talking about. I just don't claim to have any particularly authoritative answer to why, nor have I seen one - but I do know that sometimes, it does work. It did not solve the drive with an ant nest in it I was presented with once, but it slowed the ants down...